# Multi condition search in html by using php search fundtions

Tags: php, html

I am new in html and php. just made one.but have problem...

so I want to make a search function in my website...

one condition searching is working fine for me. but I want to add another condition with dropdown box ( by ip address, by company name)

```
$search_criteria = "";
if( isset($_POST['button_search']) ) {
  $search_criteria = trim(strip_tags($_POST['search']));

  $companies = $controller->getCompaniesByIP($search_criteria);
<html>
<body>

 <form method="POST" action="">

              <input type="text" style="height:25.5px;color:#000000;padding-left:5px;" placeholder="" name="search" value="<?php echo $search_criteria; ?>">
              <button type="submit" name="  " class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" name="reset"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button>

        </form>

<html>
```

Help me please

I am using one condition search like following.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: You said "I am using one condition search like following." but there is nothing following.

Comment: try using oring condition in relation.